# PHP; how do I sum a variable after $POST with issest

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have a massive file with a few variable I would like to sum(add) after they are POST.

I should note that I am doing this in TCPDF. I don't know if it makes a difference. Nonetheless, The variables I am trying to sum are being posted via an  isset function. After the variables are posted, I declared a new variable. Example `$sum = $two+$three+$four+$five;`. However, when I do this I get an undefined variable error. Ideally, I would like declare a new variable that takes the summed values and placed them in a HTML string in my TCPDF file. for example

Total: $sum

```
//var_dump($_POST);
if (isset($_POST)) {

  if(isset($_POST['two'])){ $two = $_POST['two'];}else{$two = " ";}
    if(isset($_POST['three'])){ $three = $_POST['three'];}else{$three = " ";}

    if(isset($_POST['four'])){ $four = $_POST['four'];}else{$four = " ";}
    if(isset($_POST['five'])){ $five = $_POST['five'];}else{$five = " ";}
    if(isset($_POST['six'])){ $six = $_POST['six'];}else{$six = " ";}
    if(isset($_POST['seven'])){ $seven = $_POST['seven'];}else{$seven = " ";}
    if(isset($_POST['eight'])){ $eight = $_POST['eight'];}else{$eight = " ";}
    if(isset($_POST['nine'])){ $nine = $_POST['nine'];}else{$nine = " ";}
    if(isset($_POST['ten'])){ $ten = $_POST['ten'];}else{$ten = " ";}
    if(isset($_POST['elve'])){ $elve = $_POST['elve'];}else{$elve = " ";}
    if(isset($_POST['twelv'])){ $twelv = $_POST['twelv'];}else{$twelv = " ";}
```

Comment: You haven't explained what your problem is, and I don't see the relevance of the _"massive file"_ or TCPDF.

Comment: What's the issue exactly? Once you've assigned variables to $_POST['x'] what does it matter?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe try one at at time. Its tedious but i think it might work.

```
$sum = $one + $two;
$sum = $sum +$three;`
```

`

Comment: I really can't tell if this is intended to be a serious answer, or is some attempt at humour.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. I've updated my question. The issues is that when I declare the  $sum variable  with the values from the isset function; I get an error that states "line 198 variable is undefined ". I did the same thing in DOMpdf but I didn't have any issues. That's why I mentioned I am using TCPDF.